# F# interface/abstract type and serialization

Tags: .net, f#, orleans

I am writing a little machine learning engine on top of the orleans framework with orleankka. I need a parent child class relationship where the parent supports get, set, default constructor and serialization. My attempts have failed in F#.

Update: used interface now I just need to figure out serialization of the image channel object.

```
type imagechannel = int * int * char array[][]


type Iobject =
    abstract Value : obj with get, set
    abstract FromSerial : SerializationInfo -> StreamingContext -> unit
    abstract ToSerial : SerializationInfo -> StreamingContext -> unit

type ImageChannel() =
    let mutable value : option<imagechannel> = None
    interface Iobject with
        member this.Value with get() = value :> obj and set v = value <- v :?> option<imagechannel>
        member this.FromSerial info context =

        member this.ToSerial info context =
```

Context Code:

```
type ProcessorMessage =
    | Eval of (Iobject -> Parms -> Iobject) * Parms
    | New of Iobject
    | Value
    | Load of cache
    | Save of cache
    | Trans of string * (Iobject -> Parms -> Iobject) * Parms

type Processor() =
    inherit Actor<ProcessorMessage>()

    let mutable value :option<Iobject> = None

    override this.Receive message reply = task {
      match message with
          | Eval(fn,p) -> value <- (fn value p)
          | Load(cache) -> //deserialize value
          | Save(cache) -> //serialize value
          | New(v) -> value <- v
          | Value -> reply value
          | Trans(addr,fn,p) -> let proc = this.System.ActorOf(addr)
                                proc <! New (fn value p) |> ignore

      }
```

Should I implement the serialize interface directly?
How do I override the abstract value member with a different type?
Any other suggestions?

Comment: Where are you having problems?

Comment: I have a hard time understanding the problem too - where is the point you need the serialization for?

Comment: You should speak with Yevhen Bobrov (the author) he is available on Gitter @ https://gitter.im/yevhen/Orleankka and always willing to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't want brackets in your interface definition.

```
type Iobject() =
```

Should be

```
type Iobject =
```

Comment: while this is true (`Iobject` here is a class not an interface) does this solve the OPs issue?

Comment: @Carsten I guess we'll find out when OP says what their issue is. ;-)

Comment: ...and having made it an interface (without the brackets) you'd need to put interface Iobject with ...

Comment: @Carsten @Kit I figured out the interface part but still need to figure out a good way to do the serialization. See update. Should I change the tuple `imagechannel` into a record type and use `[<Datacontract>]` attribute. Or is there a good way to serialize/deserialize a tuple of basic types?

Comment: @Orlando what serialization (framework) and what format? Personally I would not use `Datacontract`s (those day are gone IMO) - if the framework cannot handle records as they are - it's usually enough to just add the [`CLIMutable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh289724.aspx)-attribute to the record.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the Hello World sample http://tinyurl.com/pgxs6nv using interfaces and the serialization works correctly. Could you give us more info about the error?

```
type imagechannel = int * int

type IObject =
    abstract Value : obj with get, set

type ImageChannel() =
    let mutable value : option<imagechannel> = None    
    interface IObject with
      member this.Value with get() = value :> obj and set v = value <- v :?> option<imagechannel>

type ImageChannel2() =
    let mutable value : string = ""    
    interface IObject with
      member this.Value with get() = value :> obj and set v = value <- v :?> string

type Message = 
   | Greet of string
   | Hi
   | New of IObject

type Greeter() = 
   inherit Actor<Message>()   

   override this.Receive message reply = task {
      match message with
      | Greet who -> printfn "Hello %s" who
      | Hi -> printfn "Hello from F#!"
      | New iObj -> printfn "Obj %s" (iObj.Value.ToString())
   }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    printfn "Running demo. Booting cluster might take some time ...\n"

    use system = ActorSystem.Configure()
                            .Playground()
                            .Register(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                            .Done()

    let actor = system.ActorOf<Greeter>(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
    let imgChannel = ImageChannel() :> IObject
    imgChannel.Value <- Some(5,1) :> obj    

    let imgChannel2 = ImageChannel2() :> IObject
    imgChannel2.Value <- "asdasdasd" :> obj    

    let job() = task {
      do! actor <! New imgChannel
      do! actor <! New imgChannel2
      do! actor <! Hi
      do! actor <! Greet "Yevhen"
      do! actor <! Greet "AntyaDev"
    }
```

Comment: I guess I didn't want to cast things in and out of objects to move them around but still have an abstract processor. But don't think I can't have both.